# "Protected Mode" preventing "mailto:" from working

Tags: windows-7, reporting-services, internet-explorer-10

I have a report which has hyperlinks (with a `mailto:`) which opens Outlook (to send a new mail). This link works on my Windows server which has Windows 2008R2 running, but this doesn't work on my Windows 7 machine.

When I disable the "Protected mode" of my IE10 (in Windows7), this works. However, disabling Protected mode is not desirable. Can anyone help me with this? I understand this isn't a report issue but couple of fixes/workaround should exist.

Comment: "doesn't work" - in what way? Does it do nothing? Give an error (or other) message? Open something other than outlook?

Comment: Doen't work means - when I click on the 'mailto:' hyperlink,it takes to blank page in browser instead of opening new mail in outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue, with regard to the blank page showing up in the browser, when the mailto link is over a certain number of characters (around 512). My issue is on an intranet page being accessed from behind the company firewall. It began immediately after the latest round of Microsoft patches came through this past Tuesday.

It seems to be a bug in IE's latest patch. We have the site listed as an Intranet site. Intranet security is wide open, yet it does not allow the mailto to function properly. If I turn off Protected Mode in the Internet settings, it fixes the issue.

So here's the gig. It seems, to me and others at the company, that there is a bug in IE which is confusing the sites that are supposed to be Intranet (a quick properties check showed that to be true) with the sites that are on the Internet, thus giving them the wrong security settings.